# ERROR ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted:

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am trying to make a project to get some data from a public website.

This is my code so far:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

def listToString(s):  
    
    # initialize an empty string 
    str1 = " " 
    
    # return string   
    return (str1.join(s)) 

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.implicitly_wait(2)
browser.get("https://www.emlakjet.com/satilik-konut/istanbul-sariyer/3/")

i = 1
while i<=2:
    clickme = browser.find_element('xpath', "//*[@id=\"listing-search-wrapper\"]/div["+str(i)+"]")
    clickme .click()
```

But I don't know why I am getting this error:

```
------------------------
ElementClickInterceptedExceptionTraceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[84], line 28
     26 clickme= browser.find_element('xpath', "//*[@id=\"listing-search-wrapper\"]/div["+str(i)+"]")
---> 28 clickme.click()
     30 elements = browser.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "._2xeaw")

File ~\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py:93, in WebElement.click(self)
     91 def click(self) -> None:
     92     """Clicks the element."""
---> 93     self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)

File ~\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py:394, in WebElement._execute(self, command, params)
    392     params = {}
    393 params["id"] = self._id
--> 394 return self._parent.execute(command, params)

File ~\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py:344, in WebDriver.execute(self, driver_command, params)
    342 response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
    343 if response:
--> 344     self.error_handler.check_response(response)
    345     response["value"] = self._unwrap_value(response.get("value", None))
    346     return response

File ~\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py:229, in ErrorHandler.check_response(self, response)
    227         alert_text = value["alert"].get("text")
    228     raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)  # type: ignore[call-arg]  # mypy is not smart enough here
--> 229 raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)

ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <div class="_3qUI9q" data-index="71" data-id="13866619">...</div> is not clickable at point (483, 592). Other element would receive the click: <div class="_1sxDFE">...</div>
  (Session info: chrome=115.0.5790.171)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF6F54D4A62+57106]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF6F544CF52]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF6F531E2CB]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF6F535D290]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF6F535B90D]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF6F53598F5]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF6F5358B05]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF6F534EE2F]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF6F53769BA]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF6F534E746]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF6F5376BD0]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF6F538E522]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF6F5376793]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF6F534CE81]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF6F534E064]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF6F5784222+2873042]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF6F57D6590+3209792]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF6F57CF3AF+3180639]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF6F5565F25+652245]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF6F5458618]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF6F54547C4]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF6F54548BC]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF6F5444C33]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x00007FFC8D4055A0+16]
    RtlUserThreadStart [0x00007FFC8EE6485B+43]
```

This is the Xpath of the class I am trying to click:

//*[@id="listing-search-wrapper"]/div[1]

This is the full Xpath of the class I am trying to click:
/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[7]/div[1]/div[1]

I used both normal Xpath and full Xpath but it did not work/